# Updating chart.js chart with multiple datasets

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to update a chart.js chart with multiple datasets (so am calling the addData function multiple times).

However while the chart updates successfully, an increasing number of "blank" spaces are created, as observed in the below screenshot:

[image]

Here the code I have for adding data:

```
//Add and remove wind data from the renewable chart
addDataComp(renewableChart,1,'wind',windArray[windArrayIndex]);
windArrayIndex++

if (windArrayIndex >= windArray.length) {
  windArrayIndex = 0;
}

//Add and remove solar data from the renewable chart
addDataComp(renewableChart,0,'solar',solarArray[solarArrayIndex]);
solarArrayIndex++

if (solarArrayIndex >= solarArray.length) {
  solarArrayIndex = 0;
}

//Add and remove hydro data from the renewable chart
addDataComp(renewableChart,2,'hydro',hydroArray[hydroArrayIndex]);
hydroArrayIndex++

if (hydroArrayIndex >= hydroArray.length) {
  hydroArrayIndex = 0;
}






//remove data from renewable chart
removeData(renewableChart);
```

And here is the modified function I am using to add multiple datasets:

```
function addDataComp(chart, datasetIndex, label, newData) {
  chart.data.labels.push(label);
  chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data.push(newData);
  chart.update();
}
```

Please advise how this can be solved, without having to create a separate chart for each dataset?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that through calls to `addDataComp` you add the same label multiple times, that is once for dataset 0, then again the same label when you update dataset 1, etc. ?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter if the labels are the same or not, it appears that you always add three labels on the x axis and one point for each of the datasets, so the x axis gets more labels than the number of points of each dataset, hence the empty space - x labels with no corresponding value in any of the datasets. You probably don't want to add `'wind'`, `'solar'` and `'hydro'` *as labels on the x axis* each time you add one point to each of the datasets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I removed the label-adding part of the code for 2x of the datasets, leaving it for only one of them. That solved my problem.